# Separate where condition for each selected count in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel I am trying to get multiple counts like

```
      $records=DB::table('my_table')
             ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as record_count'),DB::raw('COUNT(id) as record_count_1 where status="done"'),DB::raw('COUNT(id) as record_count_2 where status="failed"'))
             ->where('record_date','>=','2020-07-12')
             ->where('sent_at','<=','2020-07-13')
             ->get();
```

So that I can get related values as

```
     pr($records[0]->record_count);
     pr($records[0]->record_count_1);
     pr($records[0]->record_count_2);
```

But there is syntax error.
How can I do this in laravel framework?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Do you want the date range in the `WHERE` clause to be applied to all counts?

Comment: yes date range will be applied to all counts

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
$records = DB::table('my_table')
    ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(id) AS record_count"),
             DB::raw("SUM(status = 'done') AS record_count_1"),
             DB::raw("SUM(status = 'failed') AS record_count_2"))
    ->where('record_date','>=','2020-07-12')
    ->where('sent_at','<=','2020-07-13')
    ->get();
```

Comment: but I want to count how many rows are there with status=done and how many are with status=failed

Comment: don't wanna SUM them

Comment: My answer does precisely this, have you tried it yet?

Comment: yes I have tried it. But this does not return any integer for second and third count

Comment: Are you certain that you have any records with done or failed status?

Comment: yes. well can you give me hint about how can I use whereIN condition in like SUM(status='done' whereIn($arr) as count_name)

Comment: Now you are changing your original question.

Comment: it does not return any error but it return 0,0 count for record_count_1 and record_count_2

Comment: @OMR Your edit broke the query.  `COUNT` counts the values 0 or 1 as 1, so your count expressions would always be the same as `COUNT(*)`.  The OP has some problem with its data, I think.

Comment: you are right @Tim Biegeleisen my edit was not suitable

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should use [Subquery Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

```
 $countDoneStatus=DB::table('my_table')->selectRaw('id,COUNT(id) as done_status_count ')
        ->where('record_date','>=','2020-07-12')
        ->where('status','done')
        ->where('sent_at','<=','2020-07-13');

    $countFailedStatus=DB::table('my_table')->selectRaw('my_table.id,COUNT(id) as failed_status_count')
        ->where('status','failed')
        ->where('record_date','>=','2020-07-12')
        ->where('sent_at','<=','2020-07-13');

    $records=DB::table('my_table')->joinSub($countDoneStatus,'countDoneStatus',function($join){
        $join->on('my_table.id', '=', 'countDoneStatus.id');
    })->joinSub($countFailedStatus,'countFailedStatus',function($join){
        $join->on('my_table.id', '=', 'countFailedStatus.id');
    })
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(my_table.id) as record_count,countFailedStatus.failed_status_count,countDoneStatus.done_status_count')
        ->where('record_date','>=','2020-07-12')
        ->where('sent_at','<=','2020-07-13')
        ->get();
```

Comment: bro I am looking for code optimization.as I have to get records for hundreds of dates in single execution of the script

Comment: this code is already optimized, note that the first two queries are not fetched from db until you use them in the third

Comment: at the end, only one query composed from those three will be excuted

Comment: note: query are executed when you use (get, first, find ....)